# how to get class of event object

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if the li element that is clicked has the 'update' class.

```
$('li.category').live('click', function(event)
{
    //my code here
});
```

I tried:

```
if (($(event.target).hasClass('update')))

if ($(this).hasClass('update'))
```

which both always return false.

How can I do this?

Comment: `$(this).hasClass('update')` would be the correct method. Are you certain you have `update` class on this element?

Comment: just a suggestion, are you sure that `update` is the right case? and not `Update`

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/AEVLJ/

Comment: Look in the debug window if the target is indeed the correct one

Comment: I'm so sorry... indeed it was a typo in the class name, it's time for me to take a break...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ($(this).hasClass('update'))` should work just fine. Are you sure the element you are testing has the `update` class? Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/yv3ba/